# Дублирование контента в подпапки на wordpress

Tags: wordpress, cms, wordpress-multisite

Есть сайт на движке wordpress. Нужно создать подпапки, сделал через WP Multisite, возможно есть другие варианты. Большая часть контента на основном сайте и подпапках одинаковая, необходимо каким-то образом подтягивать данные из одной базы в подпапки, чтобы не дублировать контент. Понятия не имею как это можно реализовать, зашел в тупик

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/function/switch_to_blog

Comment: Для чего "нужно создать подпапки"? Вангую для мультиязычности..